# Java FX как заставить AnchorPane заполнить родительский компонент?

Tags: javafx, scene-builder

Есть вот такая иерархия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Которая визуально выглядит вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы при изменении размера окна размер левой ячейки BorderPane (с надписями) не изменялся, а графики, находящиеся в центральной ячейке, растягивались таким образом, чтобы занимать каждый свою половину родительской ячейки.

Хотела поместить графики в AnchorPane и установить привязки, но, если поставить постоянные значения размера в свойствах AnchorPane, то при увеличении окна его размер не меняется, а если поставить USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, то графики автоматически помещаются в одно место один над другим.

Как сделать так, чтобы AnchorPane растягивался по размеру ячейки BorderPane? Или AnchorPane не нужен и есть другой способ?

Comment: Если у вас просто элементы выстроены вертикально можно попробовать VBox. Я попробовал поместить AnchorPane в Border и он занимает всю отведенную область при растяжении. Может проблема с графиками внутри Anchor?

Comment: А можете конкретнее описать, какие свойства нужно поставить у этих элементов?